# Odd timezone behaviour in python (pytz)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, pytz

I'm encountering a strange issue with timezones in python that I've boiled down to a few lines of code:

```
from datetime import time, datetime
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('Canada/Pacific')
d = datetime.now(tz=tz)
t = time(tzinfo=tz)
```

When inspecting the tzinfo objects in `d` and `t`, the one in `t` gives a timezone with a utc-offset of 8:12, while the one in `d` gives a utc-offset of just 8 hours, which is the correct offset. The `tz` instance also gives a utc-offset of 8:12. What's with the extra 12 minutes?

I realize that `datetime.now()` is dependent on when you run the code, so I will say that I ran it a few minutes before posting this on StackOverflow and saw the same error. Can someone more knowledgable on timezones help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Additionally, I am in the PST timezone currently, living in Vancouver, Canada.

Comment: The documentation of `datetime.time` says "An idealized time, independent of any particular day, assuming that every day has exactly 24*60*60 seconds. (There is no notion of “leap seconds” here.)" Maybe that's relevant? Also, can you show a [mre] which includes how you see the time offset error?

Comment: I think it’s not the right way. If you see pytz docs, they list different usage.

Comment: @RandomDavis The MRE is in the question text:
```
from datetime import time, datetime

import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Canada/Pacific')

d = datetime.now(tz=tz)

t = time(tzinfo=tz)

print(d.tzinfo._utcoffset)

print(t.tzinfo._utcoffset)

```
Just added print statements for clarity

Comment: as stated, usage is not right.

Comment: @rv.kvetch what do you mean? Usage of what?

Comment: UTC offsets of specific time zones depend on dates. Without a date, the UTC offset will fall back to LMT (local mean time) here, which is not what you might expect as you assume a current date (as in datetime.now()). I don't think this is specific to pytz; I think that time zone specific behavior just won't make much sense without a date.

Comment: Wow, the comments are obscure indeed. And rightly so because pytz is obscure.
Do *not* use pytz anymore, see [pytz: The Fastest Footgun in the West](https://blog.ganssle.io/tag/pytz.html)

Answer (score 2):

pytz is indeed strange. The standard python way since year 2018 is

```
import datetime
import zoneinfo
ca_pa = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("Canada/Pacific")
datetime.datetime.now(ca_pa)
```

Do **not** use pytz anymore.

Answer (score -1):

@Ruli the answer is just to read the documentation.

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Canada/Pacific')
dt = tz.normalize(datetime.now())
t = tz.normalize(time())
```

is the correct way of creating local times.

Comment: `datetime.now(tz)` is perfectly fine, no need to normalize.

Comment: Downvoted for saying _is the correct way_. Hint: Do *not* use pytz anymore.

Comment: Yep. I'm re-commenting because @WolfgangKuehn is probably right. It seems like it's mostly recommended to use zoneinfo instead of pytz