# datetime.datetime.now() is five minutes off

Tags: python, django

I'm currently developing a django backend. I use `auto_now_add=True` in my model to populate a start point on `create()`. I use `datetime.datetime.now()` to add an endpoint on `update()`. The entire code for that is `datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)`.

Here's an example for an instance that was created at `2023-01-21T19:26:04.561888Z` and updated only seconds later.

[image]

As you can see, the endpoint populated on `update()` is somehow before the startpoint, which is not intended behavior.

Thank you

Comment: Some additional information: When printing, the result looks like this `2023-01-21 20:40:57.840847+01:05`. I have absolutely no idea why the timezone is set as +01:05

Comment: The comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70100671/5320906) might be interesting.  The conclusion there (and in other answers) seems to be to avoid pytz if you can.

Comment: What is your `settings.TIME_ZONE` value?

Comment: It's Europe/Vienna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by using `timezone.now()` from `django.utils.timezone`. It still uses pytz in the background but it seems to be working. It's the same function `auto_add_now` uses.